# UIScrollView Not Scrolling All The Way Up/Down

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, sprite-kit, swift2

I am currently using `SpriteKit` + `UIScrollView` + `SKCameraNode` to create a scrolling game. I am currently trying to reverse the direction of the `UIScrollView` in the vertical direction, as the scroll view seems to do it backwards from what is intuitive.

My solution to this was to put the `contentOffset` from the start for the scroll view to the max height, and set the camera's position to the y position in the other direction.

However, the scrolling stops halfway down at (0, 320) when it should go to (0, 0).

Here is the code for the scroll view:

```
let contentSize = CGSize(width: 1575, height: 760) //adjust depending on level
self.height = contentSize.height
scrollView.contentSize = contentSize
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, contentSize.height / 2)
```

Here is the code when the scroll view scrolls:

```
    let contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, self.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    self.gScene.setContentOffset(contentOffset)
```

And here is the code for setting the content offset:

```
self.camera!.position = CGPointMake(ogPos.x + contentOffset.x, ogPos.y + contentOffset.y)
```

So the camera works and scrolls in the correct direction now; however, the scrolling's content offset gets stuck at (0, 320) for no reason, and it refuses to scroll further down. If you have any ideas I'd love to hear them! Thanks!

EDIT: I also tried making the UIScrollView's contentSize with a negative height, but then it cannot scroll at all.

I just discovered that it stops short by the size of the view.

Comment: Is there any reason why are you using a `UIScrollView` with `SpriteKit` and not making everything from the scene controller?

Comment: @aramusss I am using the `UIScrollView` to move around the camera in `SpriteKit`. Also, I just noticed that the position that the scroll view gets stuck at changes depending on the device size... Is there a better way to scroll the camera?

Comment: Even though `SpriteKit` and `UIKit` can work together, it is not recomendable to mix them a lot. You should use the `update:` method in your `SKScene` to update the background and every other `SKNode`, giving the illusion of scroll.

Comment: @aramusss How would I trace the player touching and scrolling though? I am trying to make it so you can drag around with your finger, not like an infinitely scrolling background/level. I just want the camera to move around the scene according to scroll.

Comment: OK now i create an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that it was stopping short by the size of the view's frame. I fixed the issue by simply adding an inset the size of the view's frame so it goes that much farther.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to mix `UIKit` and `SpriteKit` a lot, because they work differently (different positions, different units, etc).

If you want to drag the `MainScene` around, you can do this:

In our `MainScene` we create:

```
let background:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
var lastTouch : CGPoint?
```

We will add background to our scene, and every `SKNode` as a child to this background (platforms, the player, or whatever you want to show).

Then, in `touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)`, we want to get the user touch and move this background depending in the user touch movement. A basic implementation would be:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    var touch : UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch
    lastTouch = touch .locationInNode(self)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch moves */
    var touch : UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var touchLocation : CGPoint = touch .locationInNode(self)

    //We uptade the background position
    background.position = CGPointMake(background.position.x + (touchLocation.x - lastTouch!.x), background.position.y + (touchLocation.y - lastTouch!.y))

    //We update the lastTouch
    lastTouch = touchLocation;
}
```

If you wanted to move automatically the `MainScene`, you should move `background` in the `update:` method.

Comment: The fact that I am using sprite kit, should not change the fact that the `UIScrollView` will not scroll all the way to the top... I am also using the scroll view for the purpose of zooming, not just the scrolling.

Comment: It is just bad practice and it will take you not just to that problems, but to many more in the future. If you want to zoom, set `background.scale` property :D

Comment: Right but then I'd also have to use some sort of gesture recognizer. I'm not sure what problems you are really referring to...

Comment: The thing is that `UIKit` is prepared to use for "normal" iOS apps, and `SpriteKit` for games. `UIKit` is much more closed to customisation, and will lead to worse code or difficult to maintain. With SpriteKit you will have to code more, and repeat maybe `UIKit` functionalities, but you will always have the door open to add many more graphic features when you want to without ugly workarounds.

Comment: Well regardless I would still like to know a fix to the problem of the `UIScrollView` not scrolling far enough... Even if it is not applicable towards this `SpriteKit` project, in the future I would want to know why this doesn't work, as I would use pretty much the same code for a non `SpriteKit` project.

Comment: I ended up using a similar method; however, I rewrote it with zooming, as well as using an `SKCameraNode` instead of a background element.